# How to find percentage change of two BigNumbers of ether.js?

Tags: ethers.js, bignumber, math

So I have this for calculating percentage change between two BigNumbers:

```js
const percentageChange = (a: BigNumber, b: BigNumber) => b.sub(a).div(a).mul(BigNumber.from('100'))
```

Now the issue is when I call `toString()` or `toNumber()` on it I always get `0`.

The `a` and `b` are numbers in wei and are very close together, so percentage should be something like `0.000021` or some such.

How do I calculate the percentage and get JS-native type without rounding it to zero?

Answer (score 0):

BigNumbers don't accept decimal points, it means that when doing

```
b.sub(a).div(a) 
if b.sub(a) < a will always return 0
```

I would suggest you multiply for a factor for instance 1e6 a and b before doing the operations and once you have your percentage*1e6 as number, you can divided by 1e6 and multiply by 100

Hope it helps